# Echoing arguments into xargs in a bash script

Tags: bash

I want to pass some directories to a bash script, and then pass those directories to `xargs` to do work in parallel. Unfortunately I'm having trouble getting the script to do what I want.

Here is a script equivalent to mine, where I try with and without quotes:

```
echo $@ | xargs -i --max-procs=12 echo "do work in {}"
echo "$@" | xargs -i --max-procs=12 echo "do work in {}"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh d*
do work in d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9
do work in d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9
$ ./script.sh "d*"
do work in d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9
do work in d*
```

As you might have guessed, what I want is this:

```
$ ./script.sh d*
do work in d1
do work in d2
do work in d3
do work in d4
do work in d5
do work in d6
do work in d7
do work in d8
do work in d9
```

In this specific case using `find` in the script works, but in future I might not want to use directories. For example, if I were passing a list of files to create, `find` would be no use.

How do I get xargs to accept each argument as a separate item?

Comment: You can do one of two things, use the delimiter flag with xargs `-d' '` to tell it to use space as a delimiter, or use printf `printf "%s\n" $@` to separate the args by newline. Also you should use `-I{}` instead of `-i` as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: I'd use `printf`; `echo` doesn't really provide you with anything extra aside from portability issues. (Not really relevant, but you should always quote `$@`; otherwise, there's not reason to use it over `$*`.)

Comment: So, it's simply the case that `xargs` expects everything to be separated by newlines, rather than spaces? I know it's bad practice, but why does e.g. `ls | xargs` work then?

Comment: @123, `"$@"`, not unquoted `$@`.

Comment: @JackYates, `ls | xargs` *doesn't* work. Not reliably, that is. Look at how it behaves with filenames with spaces or literal quotation marks in their names.

Comment: @JackYates, ...to be a bit more clear, though: Out-of-the-box, `xargs` *does* honor spaces as delimiters; that's part of why it's so broken, since spaces are perfectly valid in filenames. (It also accepts quotes as being used to escape those spaces, but quotes are valid in filenames too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I'm aware that `ls | xargs` doesn't behave properly with files with atypical names, but simply wanted to demonstrate why I am confused about the delimiters. Could you explain why, if `xargs` does accept spaces for delimiters, my original attempt of `echo "$@" | xargs` doesn't work?

Comment: Compare your original to `echo "$@" | xargs -n 1 --max-procs=12 echo "do work in"` -- the `-n`, to tell it to only pass one argument to each `echo` instance, is essential. (Pardon the prior `gxargs` -- `--max-procs` is a GNUism, and testing on MacOS as my platform, the GNU tools have different prefixes).

Comment: ...that, or doing like I suggest in my answer and iterating over the argv list in the shells xargs starts, such as to allow each shell to be passed more than one argument.

Comment: I did try with the `-n 1` flag and I get the exact same behaviour. This is `xargs (GNU findutils) 4.5.11`.

Comment: CNR. Moreover, the behavior stated doesn't make any sense -- without `-n 1`, the behavior shown in this question is obviously correct, because `xargs` is defined and documented to pass as many arguments as possible to each command invocation run. With it, it would be a bug, and... well, to claim you found a bug in xargs is a very big, and unlikely, claim.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/024e0a643515fe1b227f

Comment: It seems the `-I{}` argument changes the behaviour: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BWmm6Fdd)

Comment: @JackYates, yes, it does, which is why I quite intentionally left it out in my example. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. I understand now. I think the fact that `-I{}` changes the behaviour deserves a separate answer with the relevant section of the man page - that was the crux of my original problem, and isn't addressed in any of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I was having difficulty with this is that the `-i` and `-I` options change the delimiters that `xargs` is expecting. That is, `echo "$@" | xargs -n 1 do-something` *does* work as expected (note: **there are caveats with this approach if you have unusual filenames**; see the other answers for more information), but `echo "$@" | xargs -I{} -n 1 do-something {}` does not. With the `-I` or `-i` flag, the separator becomes the newline character.

For example:

```
$ cat test.sh 
echo "$@" | xargs -n 1 echo "do work in" 
echo "$@" | xargs -n 1 -I{} echo "do work in {}"
$ ls
./  ../  d1/  d2/  d3/  d4/  d5/  d6/  d7/  d8/  d9/  test.sh*
$ ./test.sh d*
do work in d1
do work in d2
do work in d3
do work in d4
do work in d5
do work in d6
do work in d7
do work in d8
do work in d9
do work in d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9
```

From `man xargs`:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read
          from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate  input  items;
          instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

---

Note: per 123's comment on the original question, `-i` is deprecated:

```
   -i[replace-str]
          This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified, and
          for -I{} otherwise.  This option is deprecated; use -I instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

The tested version is below, just to stick a little bit more to the Jack Yates original question:

```
printf "%s\0" "$@" | xargs -0 -I xxx --max-procs=4 printf "do work in %s\n" 'xxx'
```

The printf is not standard way to handle the positional parameters (right?) *[ed: Charles: `printf` is POSIX-mandated functionality, and thus standard-compliant in the strict sense of the term, but the `-0` argument to `xargs` is not; however, as of the 2004 revision of the POSIX standard, no purely standards-compliant mechanisms to use xargs safely with arbitrary inputs are given. Expanding `"$@"` onto a printf command's argument list to have the format string repeated per argument is also standards-compliant; see part 9 in the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section of [the POSIX standard for printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/printf.html)]*.

I understand it is very efficient compared to number of processes needed with a while loop and shift. According to the [APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), the `printf` built-in command is a preferred replacement for `echo`.

This was tested in the following conditions:

- more than 10000 directories
- all special and unprintable chars found in **man ascii** have been used in a directory name
- man pages of printf, xargs and bash and the test confirm Charles Duffy's comments.

---

#### Prior Answer (for reference)

Version below is for reference. As written by Charles Duffy it generates error when there is special chars in directory names.

The `-L 1` option instructs `xargs` to handle each line separately.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do echo "${1}"; shift; done \
  | xargs -L 1 -I xxxx --max-procs=12 echo do work in "xxxx"
```

The test:

```
$ testscript.sh  .??* *
do work in .bashrc
do work in Downloads
do work in h2-1.2.139.jar
do work in install
do work in testscript.sh
```

Usually `shift` is used to parse argument off the command line.

`-I xxxx` has been used because `-i` is deprecated according to the xargs man page.

Comment: This isn't proof against unusual directory names -- to do that, one needs either the (both GNU and BSD) `-0` extension or the (GNU-only) `-d` extension (in bash notation, `-d $'\n'` will safely handle all filenames that don't contain literal newlines, an improvement over the defaults where quotes and whitespace are treated as syntactical).

Comment: Thanks for this bash info.
I'll give it a try and modify the example afterward.

Comment: thank you to @CharlesDuffy for the cool standard readings at http://pubs.opengroup.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass arbitrary arguments to `xargs`, the only safe way -- working correctly with all possible filenames, including filenames with literal quotes, whitespace, or other formatting -- is to NUL-delimit them and use `xargs -0`. Thus:

```
printf '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -0 sh -c 'for f; do printf "do work in %s\n" "$@"; done'
```

Otherwise, arguments like `$'hello\nworld'` -- containing, as it does, a literal newline -- will be treated as two arguments in xargs, rather than the single argument it truly is.